# Radius of convergence of power series with $x^{n^2}$ in it.

Tags: calculus, power-series

I need to find a radius of convergence of following power series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(n!)^n x^{n^2}}{n^{n^2}}.$$
The first thing I did was root test:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{(n!)^n x^{n^2}}{n^{n^2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(n!) x^{n}}{n^{n}}.$$
Now I want to use the ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+1)!x^{n+1}}{{(n+1)}^{(n+1)}}\cdot\frac{n^{n}}{(n!) x^{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\cdot x<1$$ so clearly $|x|<e$.
Is that correct way to do this? I don't know what to do next since there's $x^{n^2}$ in series.

Comment: Looks good to me! Alternatively from the root test, you could use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: You did not complete the root test.

Comment: You seem to be labouring under the delusion that the ratio test should yield the same result for the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lvert b_n\rvert$ and for the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sqrt[n]{\lvert b_n\rvert}$, which is of course complete nonsense.